# Equivalent of the java separator border in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, border, separator

I am developping a WPF application. I am wondering if there is an equivalent of the control in the image above ( the border with 'fréquence' written in it)

[image: separator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control you are looking for is called a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx)